# How to write into a notepad programmatically in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I made a program that is an onscreen keyboard. The program has some keys like normal keyboard and a textarea in bottom side. I can click the button and corresponding letters appear in the text area.

But I want to write these letters into a notepad programmitically.

How can I do that?

Edit:

So here is my sample code. How the sendkey API should behave?

```
public Form1()
{
  var myProcess = new Process
  {
    StartInfo =
    {
      FileName = "Notepad.exe",
      WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    }
  };
  myProcess.Start();
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void BtnBClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
}

private void BtnCClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to use the `SendKeys` API.

Comment: I'm going to guess you've got a much bigger problem: clicking the buttons moves the focus away from notepad.  Consider using osk.exe

Comment: I dont think SendKeys API would work as clicking buttons moves the focus away from notepad. I am expecting better solution perhaps a piece of code that works perfectly like osk.exe @NiklasB. Thanks

Comment: @Logical: SendKeys is the way to go if you don't want to code your own, virtual keyboard driver. I don't know what you mean by "clicking buttons". Of course you will have to make your app track the focus somehow, but that's a totally different problem. This is not the place were you can get a full solution to a problem in form of code. Nobody will do your work for you, but we will happily help you with specific problems. So please include a minimal, self-contained code sample that shows your own attempt and ask a *specific* question.

Comment: @Logical: Wow, please edit the question, code in a comment is really ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past i have build a similar solution by using SendKeys:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx

And here is a demo on how to send key stokes to different windows without having a focus on those windows:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18366/Sending-Keystrokes-to-another-Application-in-C

Comment: i really can't believe that -1 becz no LINK

Comment: @MDMalik: I don't understand what you mean.